# Converting a graph to a 3D diagram

Tags: 3d, geometry, coordinates, autocad, autolisp

This is a followup to my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752533/converting-a-graph-to-a-2d-diagram/59793784?noredirect=1#comment105948866_59793784)

The following code ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59793784/8281509)) can be used to generate a 2D diagram when coordinates, nodes, and edges of a graph are given.

```
(defun graph ( pts sls tls wgt )
    (   (lambda ( l )
            (foreach x l (text (cdr x) (itoa (car x)) 0.0 1))
            (mapcar
               '(lambda ( a b c / p q r )
                    (setq p (cdr (assoc a l))
                          q (cdr (assoc b l))
                          r (angle p q)
                    )
                    (entmake (list '(0 . "LINE") (cons 10 p) (cons 11 q) '(62 . 8)))
                    (text
                        (mapcar '(lambda ( x y ) (/ (+ x y) 2.0)) p q)
                        (itoa c)
                        (if (and (< (* pi 0.5) r) (<= r (* pi 1.5))) (+ r pi) r)
                        2
                    )
                )
                sls tls wgt
            )
        )
        (mapcar 'cons (vl-sort (append sls tls) '<) pts)
    )
)
(defun text ( p s a c )
    (entmake
        (list
           '(0 . "TEXT")
            (cons 10 p)
            (cons 11 p)
            (cons 50 a)
            (cons 01 s)
            (cons 62 c)
           '(40 . 2)
           '(72 . 1)
           '(73 . 2)
        )
    )
)
```

Input:

```
(graph
   '((75 25) (115 45) (90 60) (10 5) (45 0) (45 55) (0 25))
   '( 1  1  1  1  2  2  3  4   4  5  6)
   '( 2  3  4  5  3  6  6  5   7  7  7)
   '(50 10 20 80 90 90 30 20 100 40 60)
)
```

I'd like to ask for suggestions on how the above code has to be modified to draw 3D diagrams when 3D coordinates of nodes are available.

```
(graph
   '((75 25 0) (115 45 24) (90 60 21) (10 5 4) (45 0 1) (45 55 23) (0 25 123))
   '( 1  1  1  1  2  2  3  4   4  5  6)
   '( 2  3  4  5  3  6  6  5   7  7  7)
   '(50 10 20 80 90 90 30 20 100 40 60)
)
```

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in my code which is inherently restricted to a 2D environment - supplying the function with 3D coordinates should yield a 3D graph, albeit the text labelling will be parallel to the WCS plane since text is a planar object.

The following was generated using your sample coordinates:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I could generate the 3D diagram. I mistook p and q to be x and y coordinates. Could you please explain how to position the text along the line?

Comment: Whilst you can easily rotate the text to align with each line, text is planar and must reside in a given plane, and a line alone does not define a plane, hence the text could be oriented in infinitely many ways around the line.